# Can't clone git repo from gitolite on the same remote ubuntu server

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I have gitolite on the remote ubuntu 16 server that keeps also production environment (nginx server and release version of web projects).

Gitolite keeps common access project repository. Development process is on the local machines. A lot of successful pushes to gitolite project repository.

Now i'm going to deploy (clone) git project from gitolite to /var/www/project directory on the same remote ubuntu server.

To do that I've:

1. connected to the server via ssh under my regular user with sudo permission (not git user)
2. generated rsa.pub `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
3. copied rsa.pub to the keydir on the local machine with gitolite admin permissions as `git-serveruser.pub`
4. changed gitolite.conf

   `repo repositoryname
         RW+     =   git-admin git-serveruser`
5. commited and pushed changes to the server

Then i've tried to clone repository with following ssh command:

```
git clone git@localhost:repositoryname
```

Unfortunately i've got this permission error:

```
Cloning into 'repositoryname'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There is default testing repository with @all +RW permissions. So've tried this one

```
git clone git@localhost:testing
```

and got the same error...

Is't possible to clone repository from gitolite on the same remote machine? What i'm doing wrong? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you place the private key in the user SSH directory? (e.g. `~/.ssh`)

Comment: @AndrzejZabost yes

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, try with

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /full/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa' git clone git@localhost:repositoryname
```

If it fails, double check the [ssh troubleshooting](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/sts/), in particular check that your public key does end up in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`